# How to play sound on both speaker in iPhone programmatically during a phone call

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, core-audio, avaudioplayer

I would like to know how to play sound on both the iPhone speakers during a call.

It is working fine when I'm trying it when iPhone is not on the call.

The actual problem I'm facing is: When i have play sound from both speaker and phone was not on call it working fine. But if iPhone is switched to a call and I am trying to play sound no sound is playing.

Comment: I think this is the default behavior from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I very much doubt it is possible.

A telephone is an emergency communication device. The inability to make, receive or even clearly hear a phone call could literally kill someone. Consequently, the iPhone API strongly protects the integrity of the phone before all other functions.

Even if you did figure out a way, I doubt Apple would let it through. (Think of the liability issues for them and you!) The iPhone isn't a very small laptop, its a phone with a computer attached and the phone comes first.

You should always consider that when starting a design.

Comment: Is this helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

iOS disables an apps Audio Session during phone calls.  Thus an app has no access outside its security sandbox to the mic or speaker until this audio interruption (the phone call) ends.